# How to create combat system in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Last line doesn't work and I wanna know how to give the Goblin random damage between 1-5.

```
    my_character = {'name': '','health': 30}

    print "You take a step back red eyes get closer..."
    print "A goblin holding small dagger appears"
    enemy = {'name':'Goblin','health':10}
    print enemy
    print "Goblin attacks you..."
    my_character['health'] - 10
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want goblin to hit my_character but using "my_character['health'] - 10" doesn't work.

Comment: `my_character['health'] -= 10`

Comment: I got it worked and I edited the question thanks for quick replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a random number, you can use import `randint` fromm the `random` module.

To get a number between one and five use code like this:

```
from random import randint

goblin_damage = randint(1,5)
```

This will generate a random number between one and five.

To remove this amount of damage from `player['health']` you can use `player['health'] -= goblin_damage`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why `my_character['health']` is not changed, the reason is simply that you never assign to it.  Try

```
my_character['health'] = my_character['health'] - 10
```

or, the slighter shorter

```
my_character['health'] -= 10
```

If your question is something else, then please clarify the question.

Comment: Yea I shouldn't just put out the whole thing lol I am new around here so, sorry for that."michaelpri" gave the answer I was looking for.